# How to guarantee freeing of resources being used by tasks of ThreadPoolExecutor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor for pooling threads. Everytime I want to do an IO operation like writing results to a file I make use of the submit method to execute a runnable. Below is the code I have written:

```
**ThreadPool class looks like this:**           
private static ThreadPoolExecutor executors = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 16, 25, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(2));;

public static void dispose(){
    // end all running queues and destroy this object
    executors.shutdown();
    executors.shutdownNow();
}

public static void submit(Runnable r){
    executors.submit(r);
}
```

Here is where I am submitting a runnable task to the thread pool

```
ThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            Output streamOutput = new Output(outputFileHandle.write(true));

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Thread.interrupted()){
                    streamOutput.close();
                }

                writeToFile(streamOutput);
            }
        });
```

This is what happens inside WriteFile:

```
protected void WriteToFile(Output streamOutput){
        try{
          // Write to file which can take lots of time
         }catch(Exception e){
             // print e stack trace
         }finally{
           streamOutput.close();
         }

}
```

Some threads I looked at suggested that shutdownNow() doesn't gaurantee stopping of the tasks; instead they just call .interrupt(). How should I make my Runnable handle an interrupt while its in the middle of writing to a file. Nevertheless, my objective is "to gaurantee that the stremOutput resource is closed everytime"

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Open the output in writeToFile() instead of opening it in the constructor, and use the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and apologies for a late response. How should I test that my stream is getting closed on an thread interrupt if I use a try with resource.